# Can someone explain why these two results differ in this simple SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm re-learning SQL and am currently following this [dataquest guide](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/sql-basics/). The data set is taken from the bike-sharing service Hubway, and I'm trying to answer the question: **Which stations are most frequently used for round trips?**

This question involves two tables:

Stations

[image: stations table]

Trips

[image: trips table]

Here's the proposed answer from the guide:

```
SELECT stations.station AS "Station", COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM trips 
INNER JOIN stations
ON trips.start_station = stations.id
WHERE trips.start_station = trips.end_station
GROUP BY stations.station
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

And respective output:

[image: Guide's result]

And here's my answer:

```
Select stations.station,Count(*) AS "Count"
FROM trips
INNER JOIN stations
ON stations.id = trips.start_station
WHERE trips.start_station = trips.end_station
GROUP BY trips.start_station
ORDER BY "Count" DESC
LIMIT 5
```

And respective output:

[image: My output]

My answer leaves out 2 rows that the guide's answer returned. I would like to understand why this happens because I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: The ORDER clause is very different in your implementation ...

Comment: @AlexK.: the `ORDER BY` clause is fine; they used the alias for the column rather than repeat the `COUNT(*)` expression. It is functionally the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query groups on a foreign key, the numeric `start_station` column:

```
GROUP BY trips.start_station
```

but the original is grouping on the station name:

```
GROUP BY stations.station
```

That'd be fine if there was a one-on-one mapping between station ids and station names. That's not the case here however.

Both rows that you are missing are listed *twice* in the database, under the same name but with different station ids. Grouping on station name gives you the combined counts for those names.

There are, in fact, 5 such stations. You can query for all such stations using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` (which lets you filter on aggregate results like `COUNT`, just like `WHERE` lets you filter on rows):

```
SELECT station, COUNT(id)
FROM stations
GROUP BY station
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(id), station
```

So the above shows all station names that appear at least twice, and for the Hubway dataset that produces:

```
Andrew Station - Dorchester Ave at Humboldt Pl     2
Boylston at Fairfield                              2
Charles Circle - Charles St. at Cambridge St.      2
Dudley Square                                      2
Mayor Thomas M. Menino - Government Center         2
```

We can get the return trip counts for these 5 stations, when we limit your query not by the number of rows and instead filter on duplicated station names. I've added in the station id:

```
Select stations.station, stations.id, Count(*) AS "Count"
FROM trips
INNER JOIN stations
ON stations.id = trips.start_station
WHERE trips.start_station = trips.end_station
AND stations.station in (
    SELECT stations.station
    FROM stations
    GROUP BY stations.station
    HAVING COUNT(stations.id) > 1
)
GROUP BY trips.start_station
ORDER BY "Count" DESC
```

then you get

```
Charles Circle - Charles St. at Cambridge St.     60   1410
Charles Circle - Charles St. at Cambridge St.    113   1329
Mayor Thomas M. Menino - Government Center        23    610
Boylston at Fairfield                            103    458
Boylston at Fairfield                             61    420
Mayor Thomas M. Menino - Government Center        99    380
Dudley Square                                     56    203
Andrew Station - Dorchester Ave at Humboldt Pl   104     70
Dudley Square                                    100     57
Andrew Station - Dorchester Ave at Humboldt Pl    85     29
```

For the *Charles Circle* station, 1410 + 1329 makes 2739, but the count for just the *Charles Circle* station return trips recorded against `stations.id=60` is too low to show up in your top 5 query.

Now, *why* the database has multiple ids for a number of stations with the same name, is not explained or covered in that article. I'm not sure if the author of that article realised that this is the case here, but it is not uncommon to find such errors in real-life datasets.

The ids do not overlap in time; all 5 stations use one ID until 2012-09-30, then 4 stations have changed their ID for new trips the next day, October 1st, but with *Andrew Station* apparently shut down for 8 months with the next new trip recorded on 2013-06-03.